# Flutter make index[0] to return string 1 in ListViewBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using a `ListView.Builder` and I want to to list the index in a string form. I want the string index to start from 1 instead of 0. I don't want the data of index 0 to change. I just want the number 0 to change to 1, 1 to 2 and so on.

```
ListView.builder(itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final data = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                  return ListTile(
                      onTap: () {},
                         title: Text(
                              "$index.  ${data.get('userName')} ",
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
```

This returns

```
0. userName1
1. userName2
2. userName3
....
n. userName(n+1)
```

However I want it to return something like this

```
1. userName1
2. userName2
3. userName3
....
n. userName(n)
```

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add + 1 in your String:

```
"${index + 1}.  ${data.get('userName')} ",
```